# How do I push a local folder to my github repo?

Tags: git, github

So I'm having alot of trouble trying to push my code to github.

This is my repo

[Repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQWkX.png)

As you can see I have another folder called part 7

inside Part7, I have a folder called routed anecdotes containing my little web app, But it seems to be an empty
[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwjln.png)

However that is not the case, as it is currently locally populated with my
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXKz4.png)

Initially, I cloned routed anecdotes from another website and rm-rf .git in the terminal as per the instructions. I'm thinking that had something to do with the reason why its refusing to populate my remote file?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you do:

```
git add Part7/anecdotes; 
git commit -m "Adding anecdotes to my repo, copied it from this other <name> repo and removed that previous .git folder"; 
git push
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Nope, All i did was make the main repo on github(initially it was empty), cloned it then added the part 7 folder locally, then i cloned the routed anecdotes repo into part 7. Here i rm -rf .git in the anecdotes folder. Then I went back to the main repo and git add * then pushed it, but it's refusing to populate the anecdotes folder for some reason

Comment: @tonyk: That blue-folder-with-white-arrow indicates a *submodule*, which means that on GitHub, the top level repository contains a link to the other (anecdotes-folder) repository. It does not contain the files. Apparently you removed the inner `.git` too late here.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Is there any way to sort it out or is it just best to make another repo for it?